# Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER potentially overwrite other constants?

Tags: android

I just recently started learning android

```
Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1 = 2

Activity.DEFAULT_KEYS_SHORTCUT = 2
```

Wouldn't this create potential confusion?

Answer (score 0):

There is always the *potential* for conflicts in user-defined result codes, but the point of `RESULT_FIRST_USER` is that the system will never use this value (or any greater value). Therefore, as long as *you* never do something like call `setResult(Activity.DEFAULT_KEYS_SHORTCUT)`, you don't have to worry about it.

You're also helped by the fact that result codes don't need to be globally unique. As long as a single activity keeps all of its own result codes unique, then anyone retrieving results from that activity can use its pre-defined result codes without worrying about other activities.

In other words, imagine that Activity A can return these result codes:

```
public static final int RESULT_SAVED = 1;
public static final int RESULT_DELETED = 2;
```

And imagine that Activity B can return this result code:

```
public static final int RESULT_MAGIC = 1;
```

It doesn't matter that `ActivityA.RESULT_SAVED` is the same value as `ActivityB.RESULT_MAGIC`, because you know that you're getting results from Activity A, so the Activity B codes are irrelevant.